# YACE exporter for CloudWatch Metrics does not work

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, exporter

I want to export the CloudWatch Metrics for AWS Lambda functions and hence configured the YACE exporter following [this link](https://sysdig.com/blog/monitor-aws-lambda-prometheus/)

Configured this as a cronJob as shown below. I end up with error about Missing region even though I have specified region.

Here's the cronjob:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tools

---

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: cloudwatch-metrics-exporter
  labels:
    app: cloudwatch-exporter

spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: cloudwatch-exporter
        spec:
          volumes:
            - configMap:
                defaultMode: 420
                name: yace-lambda-config
              name: yace-lambda-config
            - secret:
                defaultMode: 420
                secretName: cloudwatch-metrics-exporter-secrets
              name: cloudwatch-credentials
          containers:
            - name: yace
              image: quay.io/invisionag/yet-another-cloudwatch-exporter:v0.16.0-alpha
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5000
              volumeMounts:
                - name: yace-lambda-config
                  mountPath: /tmp/config.yml
                  subPath: config.yml
              resources:
                limits:
                  memory: "128Mi"
                  cpu: "500m"
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              securityContext:
                capabilities:
                  drop:
                    - ALL
                privileged: false
                runAsUser: 1000
                runAsNonRoot: true
                readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
                allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          automountServiceAccountToken: true
          shareProcessNamespace: false
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: false
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
          restartPolicy: OnFailure

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: yace-lambda-config
  namespace: tools
data:
  config.yml: |
    discovery:
      jobs:
      - type: lambda
        regions:
          - eu-central-1
        enableMetricData: true
        metrics:
           - name: Duration
             statistics: [ Sum, Maximum, Minimum, Average ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: Invocations
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: Errors
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: Throttles
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: DeadLetterErrors
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: DestinationDeliveryFailures
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: ProvisionedConcurrencyInvocations
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: ProvisionedConcurrencySpilloverInvocations
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: IteratorAge
             statistics: [ Average, Maximum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: ConcurrentExecutions
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: ProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization
             statistics:
             - Maximum
             period: 300
             length: 3600
           - name: UnreservedConcurrentExecutions
             statistics: [ Sum ]
             period: 300
             length: 3600
```

Error:

```
2022/12/16 08:54:28 ERROR: unable to resolve endpoint for service "tagging", region "", err: UnknownEndpointError: could not resolve endpoint
    partition: "aws", service: "tagging", region: "", known: [us-east-2 us-west-1 ap-northeast-1 ap-southeast-1 eu-west-1 eu-west-2 ap-southeast-2 eu-west-3 us-west-2 sa-east-1 us-east-1 ap-east-1 ap-northeast-2 ca-central-1 me-south-1 ap-south-1 eu-central-1 eu-north-1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: Turns out it was indentation problem with my yaml. I resolved that and now have a different issue

Here's the error:

```
{"level":"warning","msg":"NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors","time":"2022-12-16T16:35:47Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Couldn't describe resources for region eu-central-1: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors\n","time":"2022-12-16T16:35:47Z"}
```

I have provided AWS credentials via ENV variables by doing an export of necessary AWS credentials and then did `kubectl apply config.yaml`

Comment: 'doing an export of necessary AWS credentials' - what did you exactly export and how? are these non-expirable credentials?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I did export variables aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key and aws_session_token. And these are expire able credentials.